# Get files changed in latest Git commit, but if it's merge then include all commits of merge

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to get the file changes in the latest Git commit using GitPython and Python3, but I am encountering an issue when the last commit is a merge.

```
Person A: commits, push
Person B: commits, pull, merge, push
```

When I check the last commit, the result becomes the merge commit, which essentially the changes person A made because the operation merges in Person A's commit into Person B's changes. What I really need is that if the last commit is a merge, then find all commits that's part of the merge. However, I am not sure what the code is supposed to look like.

What I have right now is as follows. I am using SSH because the repo is private and requires key for access.

```
from git import Git
from git import Repo
import git, os

repo_name = 'my-repo'
repo = Repo(os.path.join('/tmp', repo_name))
ssh_executable = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'git_ssh.sh')
with repo.git.custom_environment(GIT_SSH=ssh_executable, CWD=os.getcwd()):
    repo.remotes.origin.pull()
    repo.git.diff('HEAD~1..HEAD', name_only=True)
```

Comment: Can you please describe more precisely what information you want to obtain ? I have a hard time understanding "the file changes in the latest Git commit"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see "all the files that were changed, from both sides of the merge", try `git show -m HEAD`

`git show -m --name-only HEAD` if you only want the files' names.